# UIButton image and retina display

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, retina-display

I have some button with custom background image, and here is how I do this:

```
UIImage *buttonImage2Normal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyButton.png"];

[showModal setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2Normal
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *buttonImage2Pressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyButtonPressed.png"];

[showModal setBackgroundImage:buttonImage2Pressed
                                        forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

And I made four images, greyButton.png, greyButtonPressed.png and @2x versions to support retina.

But, on retina (iPhone simulator) I see ok my buttons, but on iPhone (3G) I think that is uses bigger images because my buttons are almost without rounded corners.

**This is the right method for doing this?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing it correctly as long as you name your Retina Display images like this: `filename.png` and `filename@2x.png`

You might want to simply test by making a non-Retina image that's a red colour, then a Retina image that's a blue colour.

On iPhone Simulator with Retina scale you should be seeing a blue button and on your 3G iPhone you should be seeing a red button.

Comment: does this done automatically? I dont have to write in the code the @2x?

Comment: @BacalsoVincent Nope, you don't have to write that in the code. At least not when using `[imageNamed:@"myimage"]`